# file system error during bootup

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am getting below errors through console of the linux machine.

```
Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" to try again to boot into default mode.
systemd-fsck[160090]: /dev/sda3: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.
systemd-fsck[160090]: /dev/sda3: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
systemd-fsck[160090]: (i.e., without -a or -p options)
systemd-fsck[160108]: /dev/sda3 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
systemd-fsck[160108]: /dev/sda3: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.
systemd-fsck[160108]: /dev/sda3: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
systemd-fsck[160108]: (i.e., without -a or -p options)
systemd-fsck[160117]: /dev/sda3 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
```

The machine runs a custom linux (genband / ribbon communication).

I am unable to boot the machine using any live distro.

Comment: Do as it says, log in and run fsck.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the some inodes of filesystem on disk `/dev/sda3` are corrupted.
You will need to identify what data is kept on disk `/dev/sda3`. If its boot partition, I would recommend to attach an ISO to this server and go to rescue mode and try to repair the filesystem using fsck - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/9541

If data on disk `/dev/sda3` is application related, try to boot OS without /dev/sda3. and post successful boot, you can try repairing the filesystem on /dev/sda3 using `fsck /dev/sda3`.